# My RecyclerView inside tablayout showing only one item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have many tabs in my `tablayout` but on each tab contain only one item. it showing the Data list size is greater than 1 and my `RecyclerView` item height is `wrap_content`

Here is how I am generating the tab

```
TabPagerAdapter adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        for (Plan plan: offersPojo.getPlans()){
            if (plan.getPlan().getError() == null)
            adapter.addFragment(OffersItem.newInstance(plan), plan.getName());
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and my `TabPagerAdapter`

```
    public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

OffersItem fragment

```
public class OffersItem extends Fragment {
     private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @BindView(R.id.offerRecyclerView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    public OffersItem() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static OffersItem newInstance(Plan plan) {
        OffersItem fragment = new OffersItem();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(Constants.PLANS,plan);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);
        unbinder= ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mPMLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mPMLayoutManger);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        if (getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.PLANS) != null){
            Plan plan = (Plan) getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.PLANS);
            List<Datum> dataList = plan.getPlan().getData();
            OffersItemAdapter adapter = new OffersItemAdapter(dataList,getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
        unbinder.unbind();
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

my item layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offerTextHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSubTextView"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offerContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/new_message_notification_placeholder_text_template"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offerTextHead" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offerAmount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/offer_amount_background"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:text="0.00"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offerContent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offerValidity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDisabled"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offerContent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my `RecyclerViewAdapter`

```
public class OffersItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OffersItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<Datum> data = null;
    Activity activity = null;


    public OffersItemAdapter(List<Datum> data, Activity activity) {
        this.data = data;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offers_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Datum itemData = data.get(position);
        holder.heading.setText(itemData.getRechargeShortdesc());
        holder.offerContent.setText(itemData.getRechargeLongdesc());
        holder.offerAmount.setText(itemData.getRechargeAmount());
        holder.offerValidity.setText(String.format("Validity: %s", itemData.getRechargeValidity()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
    }

    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.offerTextHead)
        TextView heading;
        @BindView(R.id.offerContent)
        TextView offerContent;
        @BindView(R.id.offerAmount)
        TextView offerAmount;
        @BindView(R.id.offerValidity)
        TextView offerValidity;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

    }
}
```

I debugged but the Data List size is greater than one!!

Comment: in item layout set width to wrap_content to ConstraintLayout

Comment: @Pavya no. it is not working

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I made `layoutManger` orientation horizontal instead of vertical. I know that is item is not one. But I mistaken it with tab items. Sorry for your down voting.

So I changed

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mPMLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

to

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mPMLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are seeing only one at a time in your recycler view just because you set your LayoutManger property as Horizontal means you can scroll your list horizontally so you need to set your layout manager as vertical like following,

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mPMLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mPMLayoutManger);
```